# amazon cloudsearch query wrong results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I have some problem with searches including numbers and special characters like `+` or `#`. This is the text in my skills field:

> "C++, Eclipse, Ant, Java, etc"

When I run the following search:

```
search?start=0&size=20&bq=(and (filter dev 2) (and (field skills 'C++')    (or  (field main_cats '1') (field main_cats '2') (field main_cats '3') (field main_cats '4') (field main_cats '5') (field main_cats '6'))))
```

Amazon wont return this result, but when I search for 'skills C++*' or change the text from "c++," to "c++ ," then the result is correct.

Comment: Just a guess, the `+` is a special url character, is it being encoded as `%2B`? Same for `#` should be `%23`

Comment: that was my first thought but the request to amazon is urlencoded

Comment: Looks like you are using an old version of cloudsearch because when I use the `bq` parameter on `/2013-01-01/search` I get the error `Parameter 'bq' is no longer valid. Replace 'bq=query' with 'q.parser=structured&q=query'.`. I ran a test on mine with `c++` in a text field and it worked as expected. Upgrading your cloudsearch version is probably the best solution. If you can't, what version are you on? I probably can't debug without a working version but if you determine it is a "wontfix" version bug maybe on commit you can change `c++` to `cplusplus` and same in your query for special chars..

Comment: unfortunately i cannot upgrade to a newer version  

at the moment i use aws version 2011-02-01

your suggestion to replace `c++` with `cplusplus` is definitely a good idea

Comment: Another thing you can do which also helps performance is instead of searching each field you can populate a single text field with everything and only search that field. Create a text field called "searchable" and loop your skills appending text `hasSkill5` along with resume body, etc. Since you will be searching by skill ID you will not have character problems. You still store and return the display value "c++" in a text-array field or ids in an int-array. I do this with all my setups and it works great, even faceting, boosting and stuff works. Queries end up being simpler and run faster.